# summarizing and grouping rows based on rank or order of data values in R

Tags: r, group-by

My data looks like this:

| EMPLOYEE_ID | LAST_NAME | FIRST_NAME | UNIT | CITY | STATE | DATA_RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 221 | SMITH | JILL | X1 | DALLAS | TX | 2 |
| 221 | SMITH-WU | JILL |  |  | TX | 1 |
| 331 | DEVIN | MARY | X2 | HOUSTON |  | 2 |
| 331 | TRUNG | MARY |  | HOUSTON | TX | 1 |
| 441 | SWAN | ANNA-BELLE | X2 | AUBURN | CA | 1 |
| 441 | DUCK | ANNA | X3 | AUBURN |  | 2 |

I am trying to get the output to look like this (group rows by EMPLOYEE_ID) and also pick the row that has data_rank = 1 where there is a duplicate employee-id.

| EMPLOYEE_ID | LAST_NAME | FIRST_NAME | UNIT | CITY | STATE | DATA_RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 221 | SMITH-WU | JILL |  |  | TX | 1 |
| 331 | TRUNG | MARY |  | HOUSTON | TX | 1 |
| 441 | SWAN | ANNA-BELLE | X2 | AUBURN | CA | 1 |

I tried using the following code:

```
 data <- data %>%
 group_by(EMPLOYEE_ID, substr(LAST_NAME,0,4), substr(FIRST_NAME,0,3)) %>%
 mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()),funs(na.locf(., na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = FALSE))) %>%
 filter(row_number()==n())
```

But that's not quite getting me here. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need `group_by` ? Using `subset(data, DATA_RANK == 1)` should give you the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you're using `substr()`?

I believe this code should work.

```
data %>%
  group_by(EMPLOYEE_ID) %>%
  filter(DATA_RANK == 1)
```